# Function not repeating On Click?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a small Android game. My on click function however is not getting repeated... It adds one point the first time and then stops working. It looks correct to me.

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

  public void onClick(View v) {
    playerScoreField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerScore);
    int playerScore = 0;
    if(playerScore != target){
      playerScore++;
      playerScoreField.setText("You are at: " + playerScore);
    } else {
      addButton.setClickable(false);
      addButton.setEnabled(false);
      countDown.onFinish();
    }

  }  

});
```

Comment: That code will only ever display "You are at: 1"! For instance, make `playerScore` into a class member and initialise it on your `onCreate`, and delete the `int playerScore = 0;` line from `onClick`.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what I was thinking....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a logic error.  You are setting playerScore to zero on each click.  This will result in the score always being 1.   Declare your playerScore variable in a different way.